# Monaco Editor force resize editor

Tags: javascript, resize, height, monaco-editor

I use the [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/).

My full code is too long to be posted here but this is my settings:

```js
automaticLayout: true,
folding: false,
theme: 'vs-dark',
lineNumbers: 'off',
minimap: {
    enabled: false
}
```

### Problem

- When I enlarge my window, the Monaco Editor follows as intended.
- When I reduce my Window, the Monaco Editor does not resize (height).

### Question

How can I force a resize that I can trigger from my script?

### What I've tried, that did not work

What did happend was that the console message was output on every window change, but not the Monaco height.

```js
window.onresize = () => {
  console.log('Window resize');
  editor.layout();
});
```

### Demo

I enlarge first and then reduce the height by making the developer console larger/smaller.

[image]

Comment: I would expect that with `automaticLayout: true` you don't need to handle layouting the editor manually anymore.

Answer (score 8):

We have grappled with this too. The answer is to make the layout take an empty object rather than no parameter, so the resize function becomes

```
window.onresize = () => {
  console.log('Window resize');
  editor.layout({});
});
```

Note that typescript does not like this, as the object apparently should contain both width and height.

```
window.onresize = () => {
  console.log('Window resize');
  editor.layout({} as monaco.editor.IDimension);
});
```

Fixes that issue.

Comment: Note: `window.onresize` is only called when the entire browser window is resized. So, this won't help when you move e.g. a splitter between an editor instance and some other content.

Comment: Yes, we found the same. Our actual solution was very convoluted and I am not sure I would recommend it. We detect resizing using a react-resize hook, then make the Monaco editor 300px wide (smaller than our minimum) until resize is completed, then snap back to the new size with editor.layout. The issue is caused by Monaco using fixed pixel sizes internally, so the size can only ever increase when resizing.

Comment: that's solved my (same) issue, thanks!
Shouldn't we report it to monaco-repo as it seems quite counterintuitive?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a bug with the `automaticLayout` option when creating the editor. Using that option now works for me in 2023 and there is no longer any need to manually update the layout (as in some of the other answers).

```js
monaco.editor.create(elem, {
  language: 'javascript', // or whatever
  automaticLayout: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found min-height worked great:

```
height:100%
width:100%
min-height:100%
min-width:100%
```

Answer (score -1):

Can I suggest that you do post the full code using the Stack Overflow snippet/insert code button from the toolbar to give more context.

I do something similar to help redraw & resize when the window is resized and use .layout() function without any problems.

As ‘editor’ could be null or not be widely available in the scope of this window resize function, it would be good to see the code please

Comment: For many reasons I have now changed from Monaco to Codemirror. It was a bit simpler to get around issues like this. Also it's a lot faster, probably because Monaco is a few megabytes in size and Codemirror is a few kilobytes.

For the specific problem I set a height on the Codemirror wrapper which is calculated by calc, something like `calc((100vh - 3rem - 1rem - 1rem) / 2);`.